# While loop is not breaking getting error

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I am trying to retry the rabbitmq message publishing if the response from rabbitmq is `nack`. If the response is `ack` means the message which I am retrying is published then I want to break the loop. But I am getting this error. I have no idea whats this error means here.

> Cannot break/continue 1 level(s)

Here is my code

```
    while($i <= 10) {
              $this->channel->queue_declare($queueName, false, true, false, false);
              $this->channel->basic_publish($queueMsg, $exchange, '');

              $this->channel->wait_for_pending_acks();

              //Negative Ack
              $this->channel->set_nack_handler(
                  log("Message Nacked with content, start retrying ");
                  continue;
              );

              //Positive Ack
              $this->channel->set_ack_handler(
                 log("Message acked with content ");
                 break; /*I want to break this loop here once message published successfully*/
                  );
              $i++;
            }
```

Comment: The break is in the wrong spot, and so is the continue. You're passing it to the handlers when it should be before or after the code.

Comment: Thank you!. I got it. But, is there any way I can handle this. any suggestions. I want to end this while loop once there is a positive acknowledgement(in `set_ack_handler()`).

Comment: Do those functions return anything? If so, check for a positive response, then do the break/continue.

Comment: basic_publish() method is the one which is publishing message. But it returns none.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're incrementing  $i.

Answer (score 0):

not really a rabbitmq expert but as far as I can tell, the set_nack_handler expects a(n anonymous) function. now ... I don't know what the perfect way to handle this would be, but to follow your attempt *(warning, this is probably quite wrong, but it might work nevertheless)*:

```
$this->channel->set_nack_handler(function ($message) use ($i) {
    log("Message Nacked with content, start retrying ");
    $i = 100;
});
```

also *I* would expect the handlers need to be set before one is waiting like here: [example from php-amqplib](https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/blob/master/demo/amqp_publisher_with_confirms.php)